# Reducing Lines of Code in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am repeatedly performing an action on multiple columns, and would like to eliminate my redundant code. I am posting the code for the first two columns as I believe that is enough to demonstrate what I am doing, but the code is repeated for a total of 16 columns (Column E - Column T).

`OldplayerRosterLocation` with the offset is basically a "vba vlookup" for the old player to find where they are on the sheet so the proper row stats are modified as needed. It works, but I would like to reduce the redundant code.

```
'Below determines what weeks old player has already played.
'First part replaces team win/loss for that week as a value instead of
'formula so second part does not ruin sheet.
If Range("E61") = "1" Then 'Wk#1
Range("E42").Value = Range("E62")
Range("E43").Value = Range("E63")
'Second part clears weekly results for new player each weeks that the 
'old player has already played.
Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(1, 3).ClearContents
Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(2, 3).ClearContents
End If

If Range("F61") = "1" Then 'WK#2
Range("F42").Value = Range("F62")
Range("F43").Value = Range("F63")
Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(0, 4).ClearContents
Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(1, 4).ClearContents
Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(2, 4).ClearContents
End If
```

How can I simplify this code?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove a lot of unnecessary details and focus your question on a single topic. I know it may sound harsh, but readers don't really care how new you are to a topic, and mentioning things that you aren't going to ask about doesn't help anyone. Questions should describe your situation and the problem you're having, and nothing more. For future reference, when you have working code and just want to improve it, consider [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as another resource.Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be sure you could use this for your 16 columns:

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("E61:T61")
  If c = "1" Then
    c.Offset(-19, 0).Value = c.Offset(1, 0).Value
    c.Offset(-18, 0).Value = c.Offset(2, 0).Value
    For j = 0 To 2
      Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(j, c.Column - 2).ClearContents
    Next
  End If
Next
```

`c` is a range object (a cell in this case). So we use `For Each ... In` instead of `For ... To`. 
`c.Column` gives the column number of `c`. When we subtract `2`, we get the number of columns to `Offset`, where you want to `ClearContents`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Resize()` function

```
Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(0,3).Resize(3,1).ClearContents
...
Range(OldPlayerRosterLocation).Offset(0,4).Resize(3,1).ClearContents
```

It takes a single cell and creates a range spanning 3 rows and 1 column. Also commonly used for fast value transfers. For example:

```
Range("B1").Resize(100,1).Value = Range("A1").Resize(100,1).Value
```

copies 100 rows from A1 into B1. For you, I proposed the following style changes:

```
' Old Code
'Range("E42").Value = Range("E62")
'Range("E43").Value = Range("E63")

' New Code
Range("E42").Resize(2,1).Value =  Range("E62").Resize(2,1).Value
```